# Xcode Compiler Error: ld: library not found for -lPods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode5

I'm trying to use the pod library to the project "BC LitterBox", after install pod according to http://cocoapods.org/ and Complier LitterBox, I'm now down to 1 compilation error, which I can't seem to get rid of.

ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: After install pod, did you close the project and opened it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you install a pod, CocoaPods creates a new workspace that includes your project and whatever pod(s) you installed.

You'll have to close your project and open that workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are opening the .xcworkspace file, not the .xcodeproj

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this steps:

- Close `.xcworkspace` and `.xcproject` (Xcode Projects);
- Run `pod install` and `pod update`;
- Open the new `.xcworkspace`;
- `Clean` and `Build` your Project;
- Now, you are able to `run` normally.

Answer (score 0):

When I try compile my project which used CocoaPods I have following linking error:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods  
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The reason of this problem is version of CocoaPods. Project was cloned from repo, then pods was installed. But my version of cocoapods is 1.0.1. Version of cocoapods which declared in Podfile.lock  is 0.39.0.

**Solution is following(In terminal):**
*1) Uninstall CocoaPods.*
`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`

*2) Install version of cocoapods which declared in the Podfile.lock*
`sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.39.0`

*3) You can check version cocoapods:*
`gem which cocoapods`

*4) Clone project  then install dependencies*
`pod install`